# asp.net hacking attemps - doesn't look like sql injection

Tags: asp.net

I have on my asp.net site a simple contact form (WebForms).

My site has been hacked several times and few classic asp files were uploaded.

I wonder if this is related to this constant message I get from my contact form (I send my self a log file of the event after each server error).

Any idea what are they trying to do here (sent from IP: 193.201.224.132 by the way).

I was trying also to block running classic asp files on the sever (setting web.config) , but they somehow managed to change my web.config file.

```
> *[changed .asp to .asp[p] and .php to .ph[p] to prevent indexing these links] ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$ddlTitle:Mr
> ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$tbFirstName:Philipblup
> ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$tbLastName:Philipblup
> ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$tbAddress:Hello. Anddasdasdas Bye.blleh
> http://www.imcoma.com/images/images/jc/hsuv-14dafc-jimmychoo.as[p]
> http://www.slcbelgium.com/images/lv/nuh-671d88-lv.htm[l] カナダグース
> カナダで買う激安販売 エルメス メドール 電池交換激安販売 エルメスバーキン30中古 デュベティカ メンズ 青山古典
> http://www.pazarmarket.com.tr/image/media/lv-da5feb-paza.ph[p] ヴィトン
> ウィルシャー予約受付開始 http://www.pidilite.com.br/br2/lv/lv-elntwp-pidil.ph[p]
> プラダ ライン http://www.pazarmarket.com.tr/image/media/lv-b5ca33-paza.ph[p]
> list page3 ルイヴィトン ダミエ ジッピー高価値
> http://www.pidilite.com.br/br2/lv/lv-btcmay-pidil.ph[p] エルメス ピコタン
> ツートンカラー jimmy choo 財布 口コミ人気おしゃれ ジミーチュウ公式通販国内正規品
> http://www.safege.be/admin/ri/hiyhd-084173-rimowa.htm[l]
> http://www.safege.be/admin/ri/hiyhd-36d844-rimowa.htm[l]
> http://www.bilisimsoft.com.tr/userfiles/file/cg/hyy-trgwmi-canadagoose.htm[l]
> http://www.jklu.edu.in/uploads/File/he/njkd-fcf737-hermes.htm[l]
> http://www.visia.be/images/pr/nijhd-0838DA-prada.htm[l]
> http://www.cambio-automatico.it/public/jc/jimmychoo-873827-camb.ph[p]
> list page エルメス 杉本博司 カレ
> http://www.meydanav.com/UserFiles/jc/ghys-222415-jimmychoo.as[p] エルメス
> ケリー アウトレット プラダ ロゴ 意味
> http://www.entekhabkhabar.ir/files/Images/he/mojd-efac3d-hermes.htm[l]
> http://www.tijmenkoriander.be/list/lv/nhk-2e888d-lv.as[p] hqkkncl
> ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$tbTelephone:
> ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$tbFax:
> ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$tbEmail:yourmail@gmail.com
> ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$ddlTopic:General Inquiries
> ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$tbCaptcha:
> ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$tbMessage:Hello. Anddasdasdas Bye.blleh
> http://www.imcoma.com/images/images/jc/hsuv-14dafc-jimmychoo.as[p]
> http://www.slcbelgium.com/images/lv/nuh-671d88-lv.htm[l] カナダグース
> カナダで買う激安販売 エルメス メドール 電池交換激安販売 エルメスバーキン30中古 デュベティカ メンズ 青山古典
> http://www.pazarmarket.com.tr/image/media/lv-da5feb-paza.ph[p] ヴィトン
> ウィルシャー予約受付開始 http://www.pidilite.com.br/br2/lv/lv-elntwp-pidil.ph[p]
> プラダ ライン http://www.pazarmarket.com.tr/image/media/lv-b5ca33-paza.ph[p]
> list page3 ルイヴィトン ダミエ ジッピー高価値
> http://www.pidilite.com.br/br2/lv/lv-btcmay-pidil.ph[p] エルメス ピコタン
> ツートンカラー jimmy choo 財布 口コミ人気おしゃれ ジミーチュウ公式通販国内正規品
> http://www.safege.be/admin/ri/hiyhd-084173-rimowa.htm[l]
> http://www.safege.be/admin/ri/hiyhd-36d844-rimowa.htm[l]
> http://www.bilisimsoft.com.tr/userfiles/file/cg/hyy-trgwmi-canadagoose.htm[l]
> http://www.jklu.edu.in/uploads/File/he/njkd-fcf737-hermes.htm[l]
> http://www.visia.be/images/pr/nijhd-0838DA-prada.htm[l]
> http://www.cambio-automatico.it/public/jc/jimmychoo-873827-camb.ph[p]
> list page エルメス 杉本博司 カレ
> http://www.meydanav.com/UserFiles/jc/ghys-222415-jimmychoo.as[p] エルメス
> ケリー アウトレット プラダ ロゴ 意味
> http://www.entekhabkhabar.ir/files/Images/he/mojd-efac3d-hermes.htm[l]
> http://www.tijmenkoriander.be/list/lv/nhk-2e888d-lv.as[p] hqkkncl**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not related to those requests (at least not directly). That is just an attempt to posting a text containing links, in the hope that it will stick somewhere and be displayed in the page.

It's likely a script that is automatically scraping web pages looking for forms, then posting form data to the server to try to get links displayed in the page. It's not trying to hack the page, it's trying to use the page to display the links.

It's of course possible that the script also checks if the links actually show up in the page, or checks for specific error messages as response to the post, to find web sites that are more likely to be easy to hack.